# High-voltage ZVS driver

Tags: zvs

I built my first ZVS driver a while ago and had some fun making big arcs before I blew up the MOSFETs trying to make some alterations for induction heating. When it comes to this stuff I dont know exactly whats going on, but I know how to put it together well enough from a diagram.

I'm going to build another ZVS driver and I'm wondering: if I get IGBTs rated at 900 V and about 30 A, increase the capacitance, the inductance of the choke, and the number of turns on the primary, would I be able to rectify 120 VAC to about 170 VDC (with smoothing caps) and run it all with no transformer?

I know IGBTs need lower frequencies, so I figured upping the capacitance and number of turns on the primary will lower the frequency and I'm hoping that more inductance in the choke will limit the current input at 170 VDC.

Everything I see on-line says the voltage in the tank circuit is about 3-4 times the supply, so I figure 900 V for the IGBT should do it. Im just not sure about the current; would 20-30 A be enough? I can't draw more than 15 A with out tripping the breaker.

Am I on the right page here? I just don't want to order all this stuff and blow it up as soon as I turn it on.

(I have a transformer that can put out 48 V and the shorted secondary current is 10 A, but with my first ZVS it would not draw more than about 2 A, not until I made the alterations, and then it was pulling about 8 A and it made some funny sounds and POP!, there went the MOSFETs.)

[image]

Comment: Words are far less important than a schematic of what you propose.

Comment: Sorry about that, its up there now. Those are the original parts form my first one, but if i shaped out some of the parts, as i said, cold i just run it at a higher input voltage?

Comment: Well, if you blew it up on 48 volts I'd stick with 48 volts until you understood the reason (rather than go to a lethal supply which is even more likely to bust devices).

Comment: When i ran it just like in the schematic it worked like a charm. It was only once i altered it that it broke. So i want to build another one, just like the schematic but with higher rated parts and run it at a higher voltage. Thats really all I want to know. Also, i didn't include details about the alteration that lead to failure because i didn't think it was so relevant to what i wanted to know. I will say i think i know what caused the failure occurred, i just dont know the why. But so long as i stick to the original design i should be alright.... right?

Comment: I've never used that design; just seen it lots of places and whenever I read comments about folk who have used it I get the impression that it easily blows but, it could be that like you, you want to get some nice big arcs and are pushing it too far. It does have its limitations with potentially slow MOSFET on times causing excessive dissipation and that parasitic capacitance of windings may produce some ill-effects. These are my observations on the schematic and I have no practical experience of its use.

Comment: Gonna be honest, I'm not 100% sure about the parasitic capacitance of the coils, but i think the big obstacle is the voltage spike in the tank circuit (or so i have read) being too high for the mosfets reverse voltage. I guess I'm just gonna have just buy the parts and see what happens. Start it off at lower voltages tho. In a circuit like that, if i have a volt meter and i want to measure the voltage across the mosfet to see what its blocking, would i just place it across the drain and source?

Comment: You’d need an oscilloscope to see the peaks of voltage.

Comment: I dont have one of those. oh well. thanks for your input Andy :)

Comment: The real big issue with such circuits is that the are self oscillating. Anything going wrong, like a short-circuit or maybe even an "odd" spark on the output may lead to a steady state operation point in which both MOSFETs are fully on and blow in microseconds. If it works like a charm at 48V I would stick on that, going higher voltage/power without substantially improving drive and protection circuits is indeed a big hazard.

Answer (score 1):

Saturation in your RF isolation inductor is the likely cause of the midget failure. Saturation results in high currents with high drain voltages present.

Comment: What's an "RF isolation inductor"?

Comment: It is the feed coil from the dc supply to the drain circuit of the MOSFETs. It blocks the rf present in the load coil.

Comment: Strange. I would call it an inductor.